# DoCMD.OpenForm in Access - Opening a Form with limited recordset using WHERE

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I am working in MS Access. I am trying to open a Form that does not show certain recordsets to the user based on their login info (which is determined by some vba code).

Using the following DoCmd.OpenForm, the Form is opened but the recordsets I wish to hide from the user (where G_Var = YES) are only filtered out. So the user could just remove the filtered datasheet Form and see the rows (I don't want to disable the filter). What am I doing wrong?

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "Metrics", acFormDS, , "G_Var = 'NO'"
```

I was also thinking maybe I could write some sort of a query to retrieve this information. Perhaps something like:

```
rs.Open "Select * FROM Metrics WHERE G_Var = 'NO';", CurrentProject.Connection
```

I just don't understand how I would then take this queried information and output it in the form. By defining the recordsource, I was able to accomplish the task this way:

```
Private Sub btnMetrics_From_Click()

  DoCmd.OpenForm "Metrics", acFormDS
  Forms.Item("Start Form").Visible = False

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Activate()
  Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
  Dim sql As String
  Dim Boo As Boolean

    g_User = UserInfo(ap_GetUserName())
    Boo = False

rs.Open "SELECT * FROM tbl_User_Info WHERE G_Var_Access = TRUE;", CurrentProject.Connection

Do Until rs.EOF = False
    If rs.Fields("User_Name").Value = g_User Then
        Boo = True

        Exit Do
    End If
Loop

rs.Close

If Boo = True Then

Else
    Me.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM Metrics WHERE G_Var = 'NO';"
End If

    Me.Requery

End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this as your main RecordSource SQL...

```
SELECT M.*
FROM Metrics AS M,tbl_User_Info AS U
WHERE U.User_Name=CurrentUser()
AND M.G_Var LIKE IIF(U.G_Var_Access=TRUE,'*','NO')
```